# Visual Example of JavaScript Coding Standards

Tags: javascript, coding-style, standards

Our team is working to build a coding standards document for JavaScript. Things like `semi-colon use`, `spaces vs. tabs`, `curly brace usage`, `multiple var statements`, etc. I was thinking it'd be nice to include a single code block (at the end) that demonstrates our standards visually.

Fonts are sometimes displayed as a pangram to show an example of each letter. For example:

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Is there anything like this for JavaScript?

Obviously the number of syntax combinations is non-discrete, but surely the common cases could be demonstrated by a short example. Has anyone run across a code block like this?

#### Update

To be clear, I'm not looking for standards documents that are littered with isolated examples of each concept. We already have a standards document like that.

I'm looking for a ***single*** code example that incorporates the most common standards into a single example.

Comment: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript

Comment: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

Comment: http://contribute.jquery.org/style-guide/js/

Comment: https://plus.google.com/+AddyOsmani/posts/h37ZvatmKqV

Comment: https://github.com/styleguide/javascript

Comment: I appreciate the help, but all of these links are to documents with multiple, separated examples. I'm looking for a **pangram** of sorts - a single code example that demonstrates all common standards.

Comment: @bendytree being those are the top results for "javascript styleguide" in Google, and don't represent what you want, perhaps you should make one? Although I fail to see the value of such a document. If you're enforcing the code to fit the style, all of your checked in code will result in a style-compliant "pangram"

Comment: @tkone the point is not enforcement - we have git hooks for that. The goal is a concise overview of the standards. My thought is that the majority of the standards could be represented in a fairly short block of code. Style guides could be reviewed for edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can set these rules and enforce them via tools like [JSHint](http://jshint.com) and [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).

Using these tools you can set up a pre-commit hook in your SCM of choice which will run the linter/beautifier and explain if the files don't match the correct specification.

Then, everything in your repo will be an example of how to code!

It's pretty trivial to do this if you're using something like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) since there are tasks for both [JSBeautifier](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-jsbeautifier) and [JSHint](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint).

There are countless other tools that provide this functionality as well.

You could do it in

- a BASH script calling the CLI tools for these programs
- [JAKE](http://howtonode.org/intro-to-jake)
- [CAKE](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html)
- a [MAKEFILE](http://capone.mtsu.edu/csdept/FacilitiesAndResources/make.htm)
- A custom node script
- etc, etc, etc

If you purely want to document it, you can see the comments on your question pointing to several company's specific Javascript style guidelines which you can use in your place wholesale, or use to generate your own. Although I would push you to create tools to enforce these.

Comment: We are using JSLint with a pre-commit git hook. I'm looking for a simple visual example that incorporates common syntax into a single example.